# How to limit/page through results from ArcGIS SearchCursor?

Tags: python, arcgis-9.3, arcpy

I would like to get for example, the first 200 rows from a database by ArcGIS Python SearchCursor. How can I do that? I've got a featureclass which has about 500k features and reading it all in one shot is taking to long. My present code is:

```
fields = ";".join([field, "OBJECTID"])

rows = gp.searchcursor(connectionString, "", "", fields, "OBJECTID")
row = rows.Next()
while row:
    values.add(row.getValue(field))
    row = rows.Next()

return values
```

I've tried to set counter and stop iterating when it came to 50, for example. But when I would like to take another 50 records I don't know how to start from the last one that i fetched.

```
fields = ";".join([field, "OBJECTID"])
counter = 0

rows = gp.searchcursor(connectionString, "", "", fields, "OBJECTID")
row = rows.Next()
while row:
    counter += 1
    values.add(row.getValue(field))
    row = rows.Next()
        if (counter >= 50):
            break;                    

return values
```

Comment: What are you planning on doing with the batch of 50?

Comment: If your data is in a geodatabase of some sort, you could use the SQL `LIMIT` clause (or whatever it's called in your DBMS).

Comment: @NathanW after I fetch those data I would pass it via geoprocessing service to my web application (something like get unique values)
@til_b I'm using SQL SERVER (via ArcSDE) but  `arcgisscripting.searchCursor` doesn't have access to `SELECT` part of query (only `WHERE` clause) so I can not use `LIMIT, TOP` etc...

Comment: oh, arcGIS 9.3...

Comment: That wouldn't work anyway as it would only give you the TOP 50 then nothing else. Unless you did `WHERE id > 0 AND id < 50` and adjust the max and min each time

Comment: @NathanW but Ids are random numbers so I can not guarantee that ids from 0 to 50 would be representing 50 records (it could happen that id46 were deleted for ex.)

Comment: Cursor performance is MUCH better using the Data Access module (arcpy.da) of ArcGIS 10.1 so if there is any chance of upgrading ...

Comment: sorry... license limitation. :(

Comment: yay! :)  In a bit of a sticky situation then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured it out. As I said before ArcGIS make `OBJECTID` column by default and it is primary key. So having only access to WHERE clause I have to do this by this way (ofcourse it depends of db engine that are you using, in my case it is MS SQL and ORACLE server)

for MS SQL:
`OBJECTID IN ( SELECT TOP 50 OBJECTID FROM MyTable)`

for ORACLE:
`ROWNUM<=50`

thanks guys for all comments! :)

**EDIT**
so in other words my actual class look like this:
where:
connectionString = path to ArcSDE connection file
field = field which we are searching for
lastIndex = last item index that was returned in last search
pageNumber = :)

```
def get50UniqueValues(connectionString, field, lastIndex=None, pageNumber=None):
     values = []
     try:
         fields = ';'.join([field, 'OBJECTID'])

         tmp = connectionString.split('\\')
         tableName = tmp[-1]
         dbType = tmp[-2].split('@')[-1]

         if lastIndex == None and pageNumber == None:
             if dbType == 'MSSQL':
                 where = """ OBJECTID IN (
                                         SELECT TOP 50 OBJECTID
                                         FROM %(table)s
                                         WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                                                         SELECT 1
                                                         FROM %(table)s tab2
                                                         WHERE (
                                                             tab2.%(field)s = %(table)s.%(field)s
                                                             OR tab2.%(field)s IS NULL AND %(table)s.%(field)s IS NULL
                                                                 )
                                         AND tab2.OBJECTID > %(table)s.OBJECTID
                                                         )
                                         )""" % {"table":tableName,
                                                 "field":field
                                                 }

             else:
                 where = """NOT EXISTS (
                                     SELECT 1
                                     FROM %(table)s tab2
                                     WHERE (    
                                          tab2.%(field)s = %(table)s.%(field)s
                                          OR (
                                            tab2.%(field)s IS NULL AND %(table)s.%(field)s IS NULL
                                              )
                                            )
                                     AND tab2.ROWID > %(table)s.ROWID
                                     AND ROWNUM <= 50
                                       )
                                            """ % {
                                                   "table":tableName,
                                                   "field":field
                                                   }
         else:
             recordLimit = 50 * pageNumber
             if dbType == 'MSSQL':
                 where = """ OBJECTID IN (
                                         SELECT TOP 50 OBJECTID
                                         FROM %(table)s
                                         WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                                                         SELECT 1
                                                         FROM %(table)s tab2
                                                         WHERE (
                                                             tab2.%(field)s = %(table)s.%(field)s
                                                             OR tab2.%(field)s IS NULL AND %(table)s.%(field)s IS NULL
                                                                 )
                                         AND tab2.OBJECTID > %(table)s.OBJECTID
                                                         )
                             AND OBJECTID > %(lastId)d
                                         )""" % {"table":tableName,
                                                 "field":field,
                                                 "lastId":lastIndex
                                                 }
                 # ORACLE
             else:
                 where = """"NOT EXISTS (
                                             SELECT 1
                                             FROM %(table)s tab2
                                             WHERE (    
                                                   tab2.%(field)s = %(table)s.%(field)s
                                                   OR (
                                                    tab2.%(field)s IS NULL AND %(table)s.%(field)s IS NULL
                                                       )
                                                   )
                                             AND tab2.ROWID > %(table)s.ROWID
                                             AND ROWNUM < %(records)d AND ROWNUM >= %(minrecords)d
                                           )
                                   """ % {
                                           "table":tableName,
                                           "field":field,
                                           "records":recordsLimit,
                                           "minrecords":recordsLimit - 50
                                           }
         where = ' '.join(where.split())
         rows = gp.searchcursor(connectionString, where, "", fields, "OBJECTID")

         row = rows.Next()
         while row:
             values.append(u','.join([str(row.getValue(field)), str(row.getValue('OBJECTID'))]))
             row = rows.Next()

         values = '|'.join(values)
         return values
     except:
         return -1
```

Comment: @ChadCooper I can do it after 24h of post response

Comment: How does this return the next lot of 50 though?  It will only ever give you top 50.

Comment: @NathanW oh sorry mate, I forgot to update answer. Now it is complete. :)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
def take50():
    rows = gp.searchcursor(connectionString, "", "", fields, "OBJECTID")
    items = []
    for counter, row in enumerate(rows):
        items.append(row)

        # If we are not the start of the counter
        # or we are mod 50 then return a copy of
        # the items list. 
        # We also clear our internal list for the next round
        # We return using list(items) so that we pass back a copy
        # and not our internal list
        if counter % 50 == 0 and not counter == 0:
            # Use yield so that we pass back a generator
            # and we can pick up from this point next time.
            yield list(items)
            items = []

    # Return what ever is left in case we don't have exact lots of 50
    yield items

# Loop over each lot of 50.
# lot == a list of 50 items
for lot in take50():
    print lot
```

Comment: yeah it could do the trick, but by the line `gp.searchcursor(connectionString, "", "", fields, "OBJECTID")` I accualy grab *whole* dataset and throw only 50 of them which is not good performance..

Comment: Ahh I see. I don't use Arc* so I wasn't sure if searchcursor ran the results and returned the full thing.

Comment: Do you have a unique id column?

Comment: yes Arc* made it by default - `OBJECTID`. I only can change `WHERE` clause in query..

Comment: So your SQL table doesn't have it's own unique id column?

Comment: as I said... `OBJECTID` is column in SQL table (MS SQL) which ArcGIS make by default when you create layer. When you add new record to table, SDE increment +1 OBJECTID column by his own.

Comment: Can you access a view via the connection string?

Comment: I would rather not.. I ve got a many many many^1000 of layers so creating views for each separate table would be not good..

Comment: Tricky situation. Hopefully someone with more arcpy skills might be able to help.